# Synchronize between database and Hibernate Mapping Files and POJOs

Tags: java, hibernate, synchronization

I have a schema in MySQL, I used Netbeans to generate the POJOs from it. Then, I upgrade my app and modify the schema (big modification), now I want to sync my POJOs up-to-date to my schema. Please tell me how to do it, I cant re-generated the POJOs because when programming my app, I have modified the POJOs a lot and manual-sync may cause a lot of error.

Yeah, I know Bedwyr has asked this question last year. But now, Hibernate framework has upgraded many times. So maybe it has supported this feature. If it does, please tell me how to use.
Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's any roundtripping support in Hibernate Tools (which I assume NetBeans is also using for generation). What you can do is re-generate your model with your old configuration, create diffs for each class, then generate from the new schema and then apply the diffs to those classes.